# HttpsURLConnection for rest service call

Tags: httpsurlconnection

i am using HttpsURLConnection for calling POST method and i am unable to add request payload to the call. same request works when i execute manually from soapui tool.  does any one know how to do this?

Here is the java code is am using:

```
// Keystore
    String jksFile = "/Users/......jks";
    String password = "password";

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", jksFile);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", password);

    String u = "https://example.com:443/private/loan-application";

    URL url = new URL(u);

    String version = "3"; 

    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);   
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");  
    conn.setUseCaches(false);  
    conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);  
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);  
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json;v=" + version);  
    conn.setRequestProperty("Api-Key", "XYZ");

    String jsonParamString = "{\"didNumber\":\"DI457\", \" .... ";

    //Create JSONObject here
    JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();


    byte[] postData = jsonParamString.toString().getBytes();


    Map<String, List<String>> requestProperties = conn.getRequestProperties();
    displayHeaders(requestProperties);

    OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();

    out.write(postData);
    out.close();


    int respCode = conn.getResponseCode();


    System.out.println("Response headers:");
    displayHeaders(
            conn.getHeaderFields());

    InputStream is = null;
    if (respCode == 200 || respCode == 203) {
        is = conn.getInputStream();
    }

    if (is == null) {
        System.out.println("Using error stream");
        is = conn.getErrorStream();
    }

    is.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation for why your `HttpsURLConnection` call is failing is that you have not configured your SSL settings properly.  Specifically, the domain `example.com` is presenting a certificate which is not in your trust store, and therefore your program is failing during the SSL handshake.  Try adding the following code, which will configure your program to trust all certificates:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException { }
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException { }
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { return null; }
};
sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{tm}, null);
conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

Note that you should probably *not* use this code in production, because it accepts *any* site as secure.  In production, you should configure your program to only accept trusted certificates.

Comment: Thanks Tim for you reply. i dont think this is because of ssl error. I can call GET method which works fine. i get 200 status code.

Comment: Did you try adding my code?  Also, please show the error log in Tomcat.